# Graph Laplacian simple eigenvalues

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, laplacian

Is there a class of graphs (besides the path graphs) for which we know that the Laplacian L = D - A (where D is the degree matrix and A is the adjacency matrix) has simple spectrum, i.e. all Laplacian eigenvalues have multiplicity 1?

Comment: For a while, we were not sure you existed!

Comment: Roughly speaking, this is probably true for almost all graphs: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128265/how-many-distinct-eigenvalues-does-a-random-graph-have

Answer (score 3):

For a start, there's the complements of the paths. (If the Laplacian eigenvalues of a graph are all simple, then so are the eigenvalues of its complement.) Most regular graphs have only simple eigenvalues; in particular if my sage computations can be trusted then 6 of 21 cubic graphs on 10 vertices have only simple eigenvalues.

Comment: Just to complement Chris's answer: Eigenspaces of $L$ are representation spaces of the automorphism group of the graph. So a graph with many symmetries is likely to have eigenvalues of high multiplicity.